# How to convert the triggerid to hostname in ZABBIX API

Tags: python, linux, zabbix

I got some informations by ZABBIX API,the output as following:
`{'triggerid': '13669', 'description': 'Too many processes on {HOST.NAME}', 'priority': '2'}`
I want convert the triggerid to hostname or hostid,but i can't found solutions.
**Please help me!**

Comment: aha,I get it!:)

Answer (score -2):

If you usage method `template.get` un params i using

```
params": {
    "filter": {"value": "1"},
    "selectHosts":"extend",
    "sortfield": "lastchange",
    "limit": 20,
    },
```

and have error text, `hostid` and other useful information.
Write this answer just becouse have a same problem and TC dont write answer